# Comparing failure rates between 2 products with different number of deployed equipment

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, group-differences, hazard

I have the following scenario, which I am trying to better understand. There are 2 different brands or groups of devices performing the same functionality as such:
- Product/Brand 1 has 4,323 devices in service
- Product/Brand 2 has 1,644 devices in service

The table below identifies the failure/service rate required for each product group:

```
Date     Product 1    Product 2
-------------------------------  
Mar-14      106           17  
Apr-14      136           22  
May-14      152            8  
Jun-14      178           11    
Jul-14      266           17  
Aug-14      159           22  
Sep-14      209           37  
Oct-14      349           83  
Nov-14      416           26  
Dec-14      301           20  
Jan-15      190           25  
Feb-15      129           44     
Mar-15       83           41  
Apr-15       75           14
```

I am trying to understand whether the difference in the number of failures/service calls for the two products is attributable solely to the difference in the number of items in service, or whether there is evidence of a difference in the tfailure/servicing rate between products 1 & 2?

My initial approach is to take the monthly ratio of each group (failure/devices in service) to get the percentage of total device failures as seen here:

```
Date      Product 1     Product 2  
---------------------------------
Mar-14      0.025         0.010  
Apr-14      0.031         0.013  
May-14      0.035         0.005  
Jun-14      0.041         0.007  
Jul-14      0.062         0.010  
Aug-14      0.037         0.013  
Sep-14      0.048         0.023  
Oct-14      0.081         0.050  
Nov-14      0.096         0.016  
Dec-14      0.070         0.012  
Jan-15      0.044         0.015  
Feb-15      0.030         0.027  
Mar-15      0.019         0.025  
Apr-15      0.017         0.009
```

If I average this over the 13 months of data, I have a failure/serving rate for 0.045 for Product 1 and 0.017 for Product 2. Then if I divide this by the units in service I get Product 1 as 1.05E-05 and Product 2 as 1.02E-05 which seems to me to imply that Product 1 has a failure rate of 3% more than Product 2.

My question is am I going about this the right way and what statistical tools are there to identify whether the difference between the failures are significant or an artifact of a larger population?

Comment: Hi Jeff.  I think I understand your question, but would it be possible to get a little more detail?

Comment: For example:  1) Does your data start from the introduction of these items into service, or it this just a random snapshot in time?  2)  When items fail, are they removed from service (population shrinks over time) or are they repaired/replaced?  3)  If they are being repaired/replaced, does this take any significant amount of time?  4) Is the usage of these items relatively constant from month to month, or are there seasonal effects (e.g., sanding trucks used more in winter)?

Comment: Hi Confused-cius, this data represents 13 months and it is assumed all of the units for both products were in service for the entire time frame. When a repair is required the unit my be unavailable for a short period of time, but is never "removed" from service. These represent lower severity issues, so it is most likely the device is still "in-service", but degraded and requires someone to investigate the cause of the alarm/notification from the unit. So in short 1) we assume data represents start, 2) population does not change, 3) minimal service time, 4) usage is constant.

Comment: Hopefully to avoid confusion, here is a more simplified version of the question. If I have group 1 with 5 units, and group 2 with 10 units and over a 5 month period group 1 has 1 failure per month and group 2 has 2 failures per month, then on average group 1 failure rate is 20% and group 2 failure rate is 20%. However (assuming I had more samples) a t-test to compare the means between the groups I would have a mean of 1 for group 1 and mean of 2 for group 2 and the difference would be significant. So from a percentage the groups are similar, but statistically are they?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your questions and follow-up comments, you're looking for a way to test for differences in the failure rate for two different components. In your specific example, you have the observed number of failures for two different products over a 14 month span.  Let's take a look at your data:

[image: Plot of events as a function of time]

Here we encounter our first issue -- the plot of the data suggests that the failure rates for both products do not remain constant as a function of time.

**Testing equivalence of multiple Poisson rates**

We can test this observation more rigorously using a form of the $\chi^2$-test.  Let $Y_{k}$ denote the number of events observed in the $k$-th month, and let us define the test statistic $Q$ as
$$
Q = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{(Y_{k}-\lambda N t_{k})^{2}}{\lambda N t_{k}},
$$
where $N$ denotes the number of items in the population subject to failures, $t_{k}$ denotes the length of the $k$-th month in days, and
$$
\lambda=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{K}Y_{k}}{N \sum_{k=1}^{K}t_{k}}.
$$
If the failure rate is constant across all $k$ bins, then the test statistic $Q$ will be approximately $\chi^{2}$-distributed with $K-1$ degrees of freedom.

Using Product 1 as an example, we find $\lambda = \frac{2719}{(4323)(426\  \text{days})} \approx 1.476 \times 10^{-3}\ \text{failures/item/day}$, and $Q = 728.4$. Since $\chi^{2}_{13,0.95}=22.4$, we can reject the hypothesis that the failure rate for Product 1 is the same across all 14 months.  A similar analysis reaches the same conclusion for Product 2, with $\lambda' = \frac{387}{(1644)(426\  \text{days})} \approx 0.553 \times 10^{-3}\ \text{failures/item/day}$ and $Q'=174.2$.

**Comparison of two Poisson rates -- rate ratio approach**

Given that it appears the failure rates for both products are changing over time, drawing comparisons between the failure rates of the two different products will depend on the timeframe in question. For the sake of discussion, let us assume that the failure rates remain roughly constant over the span of a single month. We begin by computing the rate ratio
$$
\hat{\rho}=\frac{\hat{\lambda}_{1}}{\hat{\lambda}_{2}}=\frac{Y_{1}N_{2}t_{2}}{Y_{2}N_{1}t_{1}},
$$
where $Y_{i}$ denotes the observed counts for Product $i$, $N_{i}$ denotes the population at risk, and $t_{i}$ is the amount of time at risk. We can then compute a confidence interval for $\hat{\rho}$ using the formulae
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{\text{lower}} & = \frac{Y_{1}N_{2}t_{2}}{(Y_{2}+1)N_{1}t_{1}} \;\big/ \;F\left((1+\alpha)/2, 2 Y_{2}+2, 2 Y_{1}\right) \\
\rho_{\text{upper}} & = \frac{(Y_{1}+1)N_{2}t_{2}}{Y_{2}N_{1}t_{1}} \times F\left((1+\alpha)/2, 2 Y_{1}+2, 2 Y_{2}\right),
\end{align}
$$
Where $F(\delta,n,d)$ denotes the 100$\delta$-th percentile of an $F$-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom in the numerator and $d$ degrees of freedom in the denominator.

To demonstrate this approach using the March 2014 data, we estimate the ratio of the two failure rates to be
$$
\hat{\rho}=\frac{(106)(1644)(31)}{(17)(4323)(31)}=\frac{58\,088}{24\,497}\approx 2.37,
$$
with a 95% confidence interval given by
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{\text{lower}} & = \frac{(106)(1644)(31)}{(18)(4323)(31)} \;\big/ \;F\left(0.975, 36, 212\right) \approx 1.41 \\
\rho_{\text{upper}} & = \frac{(107)(1644)(31)}{(17)(4323)(31)} \times F\left(0.975, 214, 34 \right) \approx 4.22.
\end{align}
$$
Since this confidence interval does not include 1, we may reject the hypothesis that the failure rates for the two products were equal during March 2014.

**Additional considerations**

Since the failure rates for both products are changing with time, it might be more useful to study the form of the empirical survival function using the Kaplan-Meier estimator. This would require data giving the age of each product at the time of first failure. (Given that the items are repaired/serviced, the times to second failure, third failure, etc. could also be of interest.) In addition to highlighting differences in the expected lifetimes of the two products, comparison of the empirical distributions for the two products would also highlight infant mortality or wearout issues with one or both products, if present.

**Further reading**

The presentation of the two hypothesis tests used in this answer are drawn from Section 10.1 of [Applied Life Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471644625) by Wayne Nelson. Although the book is becoming a bit dated, it contains a broad range of practical examples.

You might also find the book [An Introduction to Reliability and Maintainability Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1577666259) by Charles Ebeling to be a useful reference -- it provides fairly broad coverage of statistical techniques for the analysis of reparable systems at a reasonably accessible level.

For a more statistically-oriented text, you might consider [Statistical Methods for Reliability Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471143286) by Meeker and Escobar.

Comment: WOW! Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation and providing references. I have so much to learn and the amount of yet undiscovered information is overwhelming. Every nugget like this is much appreciated.

Comment: @Jeff Glad you found the answer useful.  Please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.  (Note there is no obligation to do this.)  As you gain additional reputation, please consider up-voting good questions and helpful answers by clicking on the up / down "arrows", because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.